# In Shadow Hunters, can Bob’s special ability be triggered before damage is reduced?

Tags: shadow-hunters

If Bob attacks a character equipped with the Holy Robe and rolls a 2 for damage, can Bob's special ability be immediately triggered? Or, does the Holy Robe reduce the damage Bob would inflict before Bob can choose to activate his special ability?

Bob's special ability:

> If you inflict 2 or more damage to a character, you may take an Equipment card of your choice from that character instead of giving them damage.

Holy Robe's ext:

> Your attacks do 1 less damage and the amount of damage you receive from attacks is reduced by 1 point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no, Bob's special ability does not trigger.

Bob's ability requires you to inflict 2 or more damage, and while you may *roll* 2 damage, you only *inflict* 1 point of damage.